# Jekyll compiling seems WAY too slow

Tags: optimization, build, jekyll

I'm building a site with Jekyll for the first time. I'm loving it so far; my only problem is the exceedingly long build times. Right now, when I run `jekyll build`, it takes about 30 seconds to generate the site.

30 seconds might not seem like a lot, but at the moment, **the entire site only has ONE post, 8 includes, 8 layouts, and 2 small plugins**. I haven't abused liquid tags to my knowledge, and if I remove the plugins, it still takes just as long.

When searching for an answer, all I can find are people who have huge blogs with hundreds of posts. Since I only have one post, that's obviously not the issue - there's something else going on here to make it take so long.

Here is my site's github repository: https://github.com/keithpickering/kpd/

My questions are as follows:

1. What are some possible reasons for Jekyll building so slowly when it doesn't have all that much to build?
2. If Jekyll is just inherently slow, is there a simple way to compile my CSS and JS separately, leaving Jekyll to deal with just the markup? Right now I have Jekyll ignore my "css" and "js" folders, instead having Grunt minify, prefix, and compile those files automatically. I've also never used Grunt before so I have no idea if this is some sort of absurdly hacky solution that I'm using.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Should've mentioned this sooner, but I'm on Windows 8.1 x64. I'm beginning to think Jekyll just has shaky support for Windows.

Comment: A repository address is necessary in your case.

Comment: What is the format: Markdown, Textile, HTML? Which are the versions of the converters (e.g. Jekyll, RedCloth, RedCarpet, Kramdown, etc.etc.)? What do the plugins do? For instance, with the old RedCloth, my Jekyll builds were pretty slow, but with the new version, they are almost instantaneous. If a plugin does something very slowly, that also affects the speed. Etc.etc.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Here's my repo, sorry: https://github.com/keithpickering/kpd/

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm using Markdown for the single post I have. Jekyll version is 2.4.0. The plugins have to do with creating category pages, but like I said, it's equally slow with the plugins removed.

I have no idea what RedCloth, RedCarpet, or Kramdown are :p

Comment: RedCloth etc. are markup language converters. RedCloth for Textile, RedCarpet etc. for Markdown. Are you using a highlighter? If yes, and it is pygments, find out which version it is.

Comment: No highlighter yet, I wanted to keep it pretty simple to start. Also, I did a little research and I do have RedCarpet - I wasn't aware of it since I just used RubyInstaller to install everything.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem, but luckily found the reason and a solution:

My jekyll setup wasn't using any plugins, no complicated liquid tags, only contained 3 sample posts and nothing else. But building the site still took 6 seconds on average.

Only when I removed everthing in the directory step by step I found out what was causing the long build times: the `node_modules` folder.

You can exclude the `node_modules` directory from the jekyll conversion by putting the following in `_config.yml`:

```
exclude: [node_modules]
```

Or:

```
exclude:
    - node_modules
```

More information about `exclude` can be found in the jekyll [documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration).

Comment: This worked for me too, went from 20s generate time to just moments.

Comment: I love you. This just saved my life. Went from 40+ seconds to ~1.

Comment: Worked for me! this should be documented somewhere

Comment: I really love you. This should be STICKY in any jekyll development board out there!

Comment: This worked for me - though in my case I just had a bunch of dumb image files in a folder I had forgotten about.

Answer (score 10):

You could render only the latest post:

```
jekyll serve --watch --limit_posts 1
```

It is almost twice faster, in my case.

UPDATE:

Even better, rebuild only what is changed:

```
jekyll serve --incremental
```

Up to 30 times faster in my case! Unfortunately, works only for blog posts and some pages.

Comment: ```jekyll serve --incremental``` - can't believe, why I didn't look at this issue earlier, my site was re-generating very slow (about 35 seconds), now it's about second.

Answer (score 2):

I had super slow Jekyll build times when using the `octopress-minify-html` gem to minify my html.

To expedite build times in development, I added `minify_html: false` to my `_config.yml` file.

This one change brought build times from over 60 seconds to ~1 second (!).

Answer (score 1):

I've benchmarked a new jekyll site and your repository with [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).
Same time, around 5 seconds.

The problem is somewhere else. I think your ruby / gems install has a problem. Reinstall.

On the assets side (js, css) Jekyll is good at (sass, coffeescript) and you can use [jekyll assets](https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets) for minification and other optimization things. Performance overhead is not a problem with this solution.

Same for Grunt/Gulp but this implies that you also manage a node.js installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try reinstalling Ruby and report back.

Jekyll Assets seems pretty cool; would you say there's any benefit to using it instead of Grunt for minification/etc?

Comment: Just uninstalled and reinstalled Ruby along with all of my gems. I also updated Jekyll to the most recent version. Same issue as before, everything works but it's just as slow.

Comment: Tried compiling on a separate, much more powerful computer with Windows 10, the latest version of Ruby, and the latest version of Jekyll. Takes just as much time. I think Ruby and Jekyll are just absurdly slow on Windows, which is a shame considering it's what almost every person uses.

Comment: Sorry for you. That's true that windows is not always easy with some open web technologies. I'm sure that you can enjoy a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04. Take some time to learn it and you'll love it.

Comment: I've used Ubuntu before, and I don't have anything against it, but I'd rather be able to use my OS of choice for development.

Comment: Yep ! Hope You'll find a solution to this problem because I find Jekyll is a really good concept.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to run my text editor and everything else in Windows while running Ruby in a Ubuntu virtual machine. Probably not worth the effort if it's even possible.

Comment: Yo Keith ! I don't know what is your day to day work but if you don't need visual studio and photoshop, you can definitely switch to Linux. We have plenty nice IDEs from Sublime to JetBrain rockets. Be Geek !

Comment: And Jumping on Ubuntu is easy and there is a good SO site called [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Guys, I understand that Ubuntu is faster, but I don't use my PCs for just work. I highly prefer Windows for my day-to-day tasks. Also, I do need Photoshop.

I'm thinking about dual booting OSX Yosemite to solve this problem, but I think the problem at large is that this entire language is just broken in Windows. I appreciate the responses, but "switch to Linux" is not a realistic answer for me.

Comment: Sorry not `switch to linux`, better `dual boot to linux`

Answer (score 1):

> What are some possible reasons for Jekyll building so slowly when it doesn't have all that much to build?

In my case, switching from ruby 1.9.3-p448 to 2.1.3 made a huge difference: regenerating a single file took several seconds in 1.9.3, almost instantaneous in 2.1.3.

My setup was: Mac OS X 10.10, 50 posts and several tiny plugins, jekyll 2.4.0.

Comment: I've tried multiple versions of Ruby on two machines. There's just something about Windows that bottlenecks everything having to do with Ruby.