# Jekyll build time suddenly extremely long

Tags: ruby, performance, jekyll, liquid

I've suddenly gotten very long build times on this project, and I'm not sure what the reason is. It can take upwards of 60 seconds to generate, the lowest it's gone is 20 secs. I've done everything from excluding `node_modules` via this issue [Jekyll compiling seems WAY too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855552/jekyll-compiling-seems-way-too-slow), adding `--incremental` doesn't make a difference either. I've optimized images, and I've even completely reinstalled Ruby. Below is the result of `bundle exec jekyll build --profile`

```
> Configuration file: /Users/lesliebehum/Development/sary/_config.yml
>             Source: /Users/lesliebehum/Development/sary
>        Destination: /Users/lesliebehum/Development/sary/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
>       Generating... 
> 
> Filename                  | Count |  Bytes |  Time
> --------------------------+-------+--------+------
> _layouts/default.html     |     5 | 19.68K | 0.003
> _includes/menu.html       |     5 |  7.19K | 0.001 index.html                |     1 |  2.62K | 0.000
> _pages/contact.html       |     1 |  1.46K | 0.000
> _includes/treatments.html |     1 |  1.32K | 0.000
> _includes/form.html       |     1 |  1.34K | 0.000
> _includes/footer.html     |     1 |  0.94K | 0.000
> 
>  
>                     done in 68.093 seconds.  Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

It doesn't seem like anything is taking particularly long. I'm working on other Jekyll projects and those are generating at around 1 second, and they're much larger. Any insight on what may be causing this?

[Github repository here](https://github.com/itsthecheat/saryrottenberg)

Comment: If the build time increased suddenly, its most probably due to importing all those Material UI sass partials..

Comment: I suspected this might be a possibility.. I'll import just the ones I'm actually using and see if it makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: I changed that and it helped initially get it down to around 16 seconds but now it's back up to around 60 again

Comment: Try running with `bundle exec jekyll s--verbose`.When the build-ing slows down while regenerating, you may be able to tell at which file it started to slow down